# Publish Process taking too much time in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2017 for development. When I want to publish my code then it's taking too much time to open publish window in visual studio. I am really stuck with this waiting period. Please can you guide me why it's taking too much time ?

Comment: Do you have a SSD and an adequate computer (i7 and 8GB of RAM or better)? Does you computer is filled with all kind of software? Is it the only part of Visual Studio or your computer that is slow? If some, then **you should report the problem to Microsoft** using tools they provide for that inside Visual Studio.

Comment: @Phil1970 only single project is taking too much time for open Publish Screen. Other project's doesn't taking too much time for open publish screen.

Comment: Basically this project is developed with code first approach and database create using migrations.

Comment: You can always try to create a new project and move your stuff into it. That can sometime fixes mysterious problems. Be sure to make a backup first.